# ggplot labels occupying the same space

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, statistics, gplots

[Rplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ8cT.png)The values labels are occupying the same space in a way we can't read the graphic. How can I solve this? The only way I can think is to change the variable levels name itself, but the dataset is huge and I don't know how to do it either.
Is there a way to change the labels in the axis?

```
ggplot(data = brfss2013, aes(x = X_smoker3, y = educa), bins = 10) + labs(x = "Computed Smoking Status", y = "Education level") + geom_bar(stat='identity', col = "darkorange", fill = "darkorange")
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your data? It will help people answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, I'm so sorry! I didn't know how can I do this, this is my very first question here. This dataset is very huge with almost 500k observations and more than 300 variables. I'ill figure this out and post here

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the data details, but it seems to me both `X_smoker3` and `educa` are categorical variables, and you plot is trying to plot the count in each subgroups defined by different levels from those two categorical variables.

I would suggest you use colors to represent different levels of one of the categorical variables (say educa here). Then you plot will have `X_smoker3` as y_axis, `count` as x_axis, and different color represents different level of `educa`.

I don't have your data, but I use dataset `diamonds` from ggplot2 package as an example to show the solution. Both `clarity` and `color` here are categorical variables, after I flip the coordinates, levels of `clarity` will be my y_axis, `count` is x_axis, levels of `color` is represented as different colors.

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity,fill = color))+
  layer(geom = "bar",stat = "count",position = "identity")+
  coord_flip()
```

[the generated plot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PUJk.png)

Comment: Hello, I'm so sorry! I didn't know how can I do this, this is my very first question here. This dataset is very huge with almost 500k observations and more than 300 variables. I'ill figure this out and post here. And thank you very much for the help! I will try to reproduce what you said and I will come back

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce your problem, because you haven't provided a dataset, but in `ggplot` version 3.3.0 or above, you can dodge the labels. For example you could add:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity,fill = color))+
  layer(geom = "bar",stat = "count",position = "identity")+
  coord_flip() + scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=3))
```

See: https://datavizpyr.com/how-to-dodge-overlapping-text-on-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot2/

Comment: Hello, I'm so sorry! I didn't know how can I do this, this is my very first question here. This dataset is very huge with almost 500k observations and more than 300 variables. I'ill figure this out and post here. And thank you very much for the help! I will try to reproduce what you said and I will come bac